# display address on OSM

Tags: android, gps, openstreetmap

Im a student new to android and I have an application which uses OpenStreetMap view. 
I want to convert a given string address to a gps coordinations in order to show it as a point on the map. Do anyone knows how to do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is also known as [Geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding).
There exist many possible free (Reverse) Geocoding services. For instance, OSM itself uses and provides a free geocoding service called [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

I have no experiences in using it on a mobile platform, though. But should be possible to do it with not too much effort.

Hope it helps! 
Best, Matthias